# Feeding GTFS files to OTP server without restarting it?

Tags: general-transit-feed-specification, opentripplanner

I am new to OTP. AS far as I know, you would have to restart OTP server each time to feed new GTFS files. Meaning, each time when you get a new set of GTFS files, you would have to re-run the OTP server.

Is my understanding correct and, if not, how would you feed new files to the server without restarting it?

The reason I am asking this is, I am planning to use OTP server in a kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to OTP, but this 'Data has changed, service needs to be restarted' is not a new problem in service architecture.
There are various reasons why software needs to do this. Sometimes its because it caches the data, other times it creates something like a 'view' on the database. othertimes, the cache may exist with the Web server itself (apache).

Often the only way around this problem is to turn off caching, or other optimization features.

If you are concerned about downtime of the application during service restart, sometimes a more simple solution is to have a second instance running.

With two instances, you can simply shut down the first one. Traffic will be redirected to Service 2.... Then restart service 1, shut down service 2. Traffic now directs only to Service 1, which now has the updated data. restart Service 2 - happy days.

Other solutions are more based around the database and - as per above, the application server takes a 'view' of the data. the solution involves refreshing that view, which is dependant upon the application server and DB solution. you are mentioning files, which suggest the software is file based, which doesn't help you at all. maybe have a look at investigating whether OTP Server can read data from a database with no caching?